# pass empty string as variable value from ansible playbook to powershell?

Tags: powershell, ansible

I want to pass an empty string as a variable value from ansible-playbook to PowerShell file.

Ansible Code:

```
vars:
 name: {{file_name}}

tasks:
  - name: run ps1 
    win_shell: "script.ps1 -database_name {{ name }}"
    no_log: false

Powershell code 

param(

[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][AllowEmptyString()][string]$database_name 

)
```

So if there is no name in `file_name` then I want to send an empty string to PowerShell file! How can I do that?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62143859/edit) and fix the formatting. As for your question, what steps have you tried so far that are not working for you?

Comment: Hi @mdaniel thanks. I want to pass an empty string as a variable ( like name = " ")  to PowerShell file if there is no filename declared or not define.                                              I tried with win_shell: "script.ps1 -database_name {{ name | default ( ' ' ) }}.            
 but its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely you need [`| quote`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) as in `{{ name | default("") | quote }}` in order to wrap the result in shell quote variables. Without that, jinja2 does not know that you want the empty string to render as `""` instead of blank; you can also side-step that with `{{ name | default('""') }}` but that's highly unlikely to be what you want since if `name` is `"hello world"` then `{{ name | default("") }}` will render in your command as `-database_name hello world` which will almost certainly fail